# How to update field before raising UserError and keep the change from rollbacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to show a custom (warning) message upon clicking confirm button in Invoices (account.move).

The basic idea is: when user confirms new invoice check condition (is this the first time showing message?) and raise UserError if condition is true otherwise continue and create invoice.

This works fine, but i have bool field serving as a flag (Was message already shown?) and i need to update this flag (with permanent change, so that user is not stuck in a loop) before raising UserError. Unfortunately raising UserError causes database rollback so my update of flag field is always rollbacked.

Is there a way to keep the change from rollbacking? I came across Stack Overflow post with odoo cursors that looked promising, but i have no idea how to make my change permanent.

Answer (score 0):

> Onchange - [with warning raise](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/api.py#L221)

take the reference [_onchange_partner_id (Account Move)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L459)

**raise-Warning** message indication for user to perform anything with that **reference** you can use with your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on the confirm action:

```
def action_confirm(self):
  res = super(ModelName, self).action_confirm()
  if #check_my_condition:
    self.update({'field_to_be_update': 'your_updating_value'})
    raise UserError(_("Error Message"))
  return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new cursor, which won't be rollbacked.

```
def action_confirm(self):
  res = super(ModelName, self).action_confirm()
  if #check_my_condition:
    with Environment.manage():
            cr, uid, context = self.env.args
            env = Environment(cr, uid, context)
            env[self._name].browse(self.id).write({"field_name": "field_value"})
    raise UserError(_("Error Message"))
  return res
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you please explain what does the `with Enviroment.manage():` code block? I have never seen it before.